# How can I bake such a large building?

Tags: texture-baking, baking

[image]

How can I bake such a large building, without loss of quality?
I want to bake textures of this building, but I do not like the result, because textures are very much smoothed out(i want to add this model to unity)

[image]

bad((

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on what you've tried so far.